# Why getElementById returns null in module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement module pattern from an [acticle from css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/)
Here is my return object:

```
var MyModule = (function() {
  var pSettings; //private context

  return {
      settings: {
          time: Date.now(),
          myBtn: document.getElementById('myBtn')
      },

      init: function () {
          pSettings = this.settings;
          this.bindUIActions();
      },

      bindUIActions: function () {
          pSettings.myBtn.onclick = someFunction;
          console.log('binding');
      },

      someFunction: function() {
          console.log('someFunction');
      }
  }
})();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baxxabit/C856f/2/)**

When I use MyModule.init(), I have an error like `myBtn is null`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

, why is it happends?

Comment: Because there is not element with id `myBtn`.

Comment: Sorry, I have this element. Will update fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably about timing.  `document.getElementById('myBtn')` is being executed when my Module is first defined which is probably before your HTML document has been parsed and thus `myBtn` doesn't yet exist.

Your object inside of`MyModule` and all of its properties are being created at the time that `MyModule` is first defined and created.  The `myBtn` property is a static value, initialized when the property is first created.  If you want it to be a function that is evaluated only upon demand, then you must make it a function that you can call at the desired time.

You have several ways you can fix it.

1. You can stop trying to pre-fetch the `myBtn` DOM element and just fetch it upon demand only when needed.
2. You can move this javascript to the end of the `<body>` tag or put it in some sort of ready function so it won't execute until the DOM is ready.
3. You can cache `myBtn` upon first use (when the DOM is ready) rather than in advance.
4. You can change the initialization of the `myBtn` property to be in the `.init()` method when the DOM is ready.

My suggestion would be the first option.

Comment: @baxxabit - Please read what I wrote again.  I'm trying to explain to you that you are initializing the `settings.myBtn` property too early before the 'myBtn' element exists.

Comment: I have wrote comment before you update answer, thanks!

Comment: I use angularjs template, so this is a problem, why myBtn property is null in module. Thanks for explaination. Module loaded before template

Comment: @baxxabit - You can also  just initialize `myBtn` in the `.init()` method rather than in the initial definition when the DOM is ready.